# AngularJS - Toggle view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below controller function that returns me a Boolean value.

**Current HTML**:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="collapseNavbar(true)" ng-model="collNavbar">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
</a>
```

**layoutController:**

```
App.controller('layoutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.collapseNavbar = function(val) {

        return $scope.value = !val;

    }

}])
```

Based on that value I need to assign the `<body>` tag a class like yes or no.

Earlier I was using something like this to do it.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="toggle-sidebar navbar-nav">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#" ng-click="isActive = !isActive" ng-model="collNavbar">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**HTML2**

```
<body ng-class="{'yes': isActive, 'no': !isActive}" ng-controller="layoutController">
```

But I don't want my code to be in the HTML file. Instead I created a controller for it named `layoutController.js` and above is the code used in it.

I'm able to pass the Boolean as a class to the `body` tag on pageload.

But I don't know how to pass it on a click of the `a` tag where as I've passed the function using `ng-click`.

Any suggestions like how can I do it will be very helpful for me in the learning it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$scope.value` will always be false in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body ng-controller="layoutController" ng-app="App" 
                ng-class="getClass(value)">
   <a href="#" ng-click="collapseNavbar(!value)" ng-model="collNavbar">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>
 </body>
```

Controller:

```
App.controller('layoutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.collapseNavbar = function(val) {
        return $scope.value = val;
    }

    $scope.getClass = function(value) {
         return value ? 'yes': 'no';
    }

}])
```

The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

One of the ways you can setup your expression is by returning a string (or a space delimited string) representing your CSS classes.

Comment: How can I access the $scope.value in the body tag to assign the class as yes or no? yes = true and no = false.

Comment: Put the ng-controller="layoutController" on the body tag.

Comment: Do you want ng-class as a conditional attribute?

Comment: I don't want to write the `ng-class` on the body tag and display it and use a separate controller file. If I had to use it the way you've given I can simply set this on anchor tag `ng-click="isActive = !isActive" that's return me a Boolean value. I want to simply my HTML and remove the angular expression in the HTML file.

Comment: I simply wanted to return the class name in the function and return value of that function as a class in the body tag.

Comment: if you dont want to use ng-class then you need to go for custom directive

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @pixelbits. It did help me out a lot and I even did get a idea on how this stuff works. I do know that I'm going a long way in assigning the class but this does makes it more simple. Any suggestions on how can I improve such kinda things?

Comment: I think you're doing fine:) Angular concepts are simple once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
  <body ng-class="{'yes': isActive, 'no': !isActive}" ng-controller="layoutController">

    <div class="toggle-sidebar navbar-nav">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#" ng-click="collapseNavbar()" ng-model="collNavbar">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Controller

```
App.controller('layoutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.collapseNavbar = function() {

        $scope.isActive= ! $scope.isActive;

    }

}]);
```

or

HTML

```
  <body class="{{className}}" ng-controller="layoutController">

    <div class="toggle-sidebar navbar-nav">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#" ng-click="collapseNavbar()" >
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Controller

```
App.controller('layoutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.collapseNavbar = function() {

        if($scope.isActive)
           $scope.className='yes';
        else
          $scope.className='no';
        $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;

    }

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks this is too very short and good. But do let me know if you don't mind. Following this kinda practice is good or not instead of directly using the angular expression on HTML tags? +1

Comment: the best practice is always use angular directives like ng-class. we can control the values from controller.